# What is the definition of NAT throughput?

Tags: networking, router

After finding out our router is a bottleneck in our internet traffic (Bandwith should be 120 Mbit, but we get only 90 behind the router), I am looking for a faster router. But their seems to be no clear term for the WAN-to-Lan througput (and vice versa). In the specifications of a Cisco router I saw the term "NAT throughput 800 Mbit/s". I think that may be the througput number I am looking for. 
Does anyone know a definition of "NAT throughput" for routers?

Comment: Ask Cisco? Though "The maximum traffic throughput when packets have to pass through Network Address Translation" seems a reasonable assumption.

Comment: Throughput often isn't a good enough metric. You need to consider packets per second and package sizes as well.

Comment: what kind of router do you currently use?  It may not be the router.

Answer (score 2):

The most encountered limitations in a NAT-ing router are:

- Miss-configurations (auto-negotiation problems)
- Maximum bandwidth of the interfaces (e.g. are your interfaces 1Gbps capable?)
- Physical errors (problem with cables...)
- traffic with many small packets - each packet needs to be analysed to be routed
- Large connection tracking tables (those are used by NAT and [SPI firewall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stateful_firewall))
- limitations of the ASICs (not enough memory...)
- firmware related problems